# Pass the instructions of the checkbox form submission button to another button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I like to have a checkbox form that needs to be checked by participants before starting an online experiment. In a php file I have a checkbox form with a submission button “AGREE”, and in a JavaScript file I have the instructions for the behaviour of the pages with a button “NEXT”. Is there a way to deactivate the “AGREE” button of the checkbox form and pass its instruction to the “NEXT” button in the js file? Unfortunately, I could not find the right way to do it.
Thank you very much in advance, I will appreciate any help with this issue.

Function in main.js file:

```
function Consent()
{
   $("#CONSENT").dialog(
   {
     title: "Consent Form",
     height:800, width:1430,
     modal:true,
     resizable:false,
     show: "none", 
     hide: "none",      

     buttons: 
     [
        { 
            text: "Next", click: function()
            {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                Instructions1();
            }},
    ]
  });
}
```

I would like to pass this instruction inside the function Consent:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#consent').click(function() {
    if ($('input:checkbox', this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).dialog("close");
                Instructions2();
    }
    else {
        alert('Please all checkboxes!');
        return false;
    }
  });
});
```

PHP file:

```
<form id="consent" onclick="Instruction1" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="consent" value="agree" required>I have read the information sheet;   
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="consent" value="agree" required>I consent to the processing of my personal information;
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="consent" value="agree" required>I consent to participate in this study.</p>
<br>
<input required type="submit" name="consent" value="AGREE"> 
</form>
```

Comment: What are you using for the dialog? jquery-ui?

Comment: Jose, yes, I am using jquery-ui

Comment: It's not so clear what you want to achieve, do you want to show the dialog when somebody click on the checkbox?

Comment: Thank you for your interest and help and I am sorry for not being clear about that. 
If I use the code of the checkbox as it is (second code) inside the Consent function (first code), it creates an embedded form with its own submit button. As a result I get two buttons (“AGREE” and “NEXT”): the former belongs to the checkbox form and the latter to the Consent function. I would like to use the same checkbox form (second code) inside the Consent function (first code) with only the “NEXT” button. I hope it is a bit clearer now.